# Images appear in all browsers except IE

Tags: jquery, css, image, internet-explorer, loading

I just bought this template. http://bestwebsoft.com/demo_theme/unity-html5-template/

Whenever I replace any of the images on the website in Dreamweaver, they will not appear in IE. The websites images work fine as they are given to me but they will not work once I simply switch out the images. My images work fine in all other browsers. IE will show them once in a while if I reload the page but other than that it usually doesn't show any of them. I think the images might need to be placed into some jquery or CSS code instead of the source code but even the logo isn't working.

Please help!!!

Comment: Have you checked the file path to your local images versus the ones in the template?

Comment: Yup, I put them in the same place. It works in all browsers but IE.

Comment: Without knowing if you're running a localhost server, or just viewing HTML files in the browser, it could have something to do with absolute versus relative file paths. Without knowing more about your setup, there isn't much we can do. Are you getting any notifications from IE about blocking/enabling images, or allowing scripts to run?

Comment: I'm just viewing my html files in the browser. I'm not getting any IE messages.